# Middleware com ASP.NET MVC e .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

É possível adicionar algum *middleware* as rotas que irá, por exemplo, permitir ou redirecionar um usuário a acessar o painel de administração, que caso não esteja autenticado será redirecionado para a área de login? como no exemplo abaixo (Em PHP / Laravel):

```
Route::get('/login', [
    'as' => 'login',
    'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@Index',
    'middleware' => ['guest', 'throttle:12,1'],
]);
```

Minhas rotas no ASP.NET:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin.Login", url: "admin/login",
    defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new[] { "Controllers.Admin.Authentication" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin.Login.Attempt", url: "admin/login/attempt",
    defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "Attempt" },
    namespaces: new[] { "Controllers.Admin.Authentication" }
);
```

Obs: minha dúvida é a respeito de rotas no ASP.NET, o trexo de código em PHP é somente para exemplificar minha dúvida.

Comment: O que seria esse "middleware"?

Comment: Middleware é uma classe intermediária entre o Route e o Controller, onde podemos, por exemplo, checar se o usuário está autenticado ao tentar acessar o painel de administração, e caso não esteja, o middleware retorna um redirect para uma route definida, como a de login, impedindo o usuário de prosseguir sem efetuar o login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ASP.NET MVC não existe este conceito de "middleware". O que existe são arquiteturas de usuários e autenticação que podem ser incorporadas à aplicação, que é uma abordagem que, acredito, seja próxima ao *middleware* do Laravel.

A autenticação normalmente é conferida através de atributos, que podem ser nativos ou escritos pelo programador da aplicação. Para escrever seu próprio atributo ou entender como a autenticação é feita, pode começar [pelas respostas daqui do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+authorize) ou ainda [ir para os tutoriais da principal arquitetura de usuários e autenticação do ASP.NET MVC, o Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity).

Há, ainda, outras arquiteturas, mais antigas ou desenvolvidas por terceiros, [como o ASP.NET Membership](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+membership) ou ainda o [Identity Manager](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager).